# Android Gradle Issue - Flutter / Dart

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter

I have a problem with my Gradle Sync.

I use IntelliJ and Android Studio to build a Flutter / Dart App.

I added 2 new dependencies and now i have an issue with Gradle.
In Android Studio all works fine (The Gradle Sync finishes without failures or warnings), but in IntelliJ it is not working.

[image: Gradle build file screenshot]

```
* Error running Gradle: Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\stesc\Documents\Programming\timecoder-flutter\android\gradlew.bat app:properties: NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\stesc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle. If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.669 secs


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Build file 'C:\Users\stesc\Documents\Programming\timecoder-flutter\android\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'. Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
      > A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences'.
         > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':shared_preferences:classpath'.
            > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
              Searched in the following locations:
                  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
                  https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
              Required by:
                  project :shared_preferences

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

[image: More gradle build screenshot]

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your **allpojects->repositories** same like **buildscript->repositories**

If the problem still persists check if your project and shared_preferences both uses the same gradle version. If not, then you may need to make few changes in either your project or in shared_preferences project.

Answer (score 6):

**1.** Update your **gradle version** from project -> android -> build. For me :

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

**2.** Use **latest sdk tool version**

**3.** Open terminal from **Tools->Flutter** and run these following commands

```
flutter upgrade
flutter doctor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fixed for me by adding this to my build.gradle in android folder.

Answer (score 0):

- yaa It had solved for me..!
  Just go to flutter sdk folder and go to this path \flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle
  and in flutter.gradle file change from this code

---

```
    buildscript { 
        repositories { 
          jcenter() 
     maven { 
      url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' 
   }
 } 
dependencies { 
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' 
       } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it too.
Perhaps, will be useful for someone.
This was my problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/abc/Desktop/user/project/android/app/build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
   /Users/abc/Desktop/user/project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
  Command: /Users/abc/Desktop/user/project/android/gradlew app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

I went to gradle-wrapper.properties and changed this line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

try going to android/gradle folder then find the wrapper and edit it to the latest version e.g 7.6-bin ,then go to app gradle and rename the kotlin version to 1.7.0 and the build tools to 7.4.0 like this.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6- bin.zip distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStorePath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

buildscript { ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0' repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the new before gradle it solved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).