# Trouble compiling android build on Mac(Android Studio)

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

Flutter Version: 4.1.3
Android Studio: 4.2.1
Gradle version: 3.5.0

There is an issue compiling the flutter app on android device. The app is working fine on any of the iOS device.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
         Required by:
             project :
          > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
             > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
                > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
                   > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 9s
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: `* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.` - have you tried that...? stacktrace/logcat is crucial, due to unknown exception, may be plenty of reasons...

Comment: How about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66889979/1028772

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here [Android Gradle Issue - Flutter / Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479284/android-gradle-issue-flutter-dart)

Oftenly it is just corrupted Build Gradle. You need to reinstall or replace it with ver that you already have